# Replacing value inside column

Tags: sql

I'm trying to change the dollar amounts inside of a group of columns

I've tried a few WHEN and THEN combinations

I can use the select from dbo.cards to select all of the rows that I need.  And then from there these rows have a column called 'RecurringBillingAmount' and I'm trying to now change the value inside of the 'RecurringBillingAmount' column from 29.98 to 34.98

```
select * from dbo.cards WHERE productcode = '2x $19.99 SUBSCRIPTI'
WHEN RecurringBillingAmount = '29.98' THEN '34.98'
```

Comment: You want to change it just for the select, or you want to change it in the database table itself?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Update dbo.cards set RecurringBillingAmount = '34.98' where productcode = '2x $19.99 SUBSCRIPTI'

Comment: You can't just write whatever you want, and expect the program to be able to run it.  Even I don't understand what you are trying to do.  You should learn some SQL syntax before posting this question.

Comment: @yardpenalty, you're not accounting for the possibility of multiple values of `RecurringBillingAmount` within the same `productcode`. Just sayin', since I posted _almost_ the same query as an answer. :)

Comment: Looks like @yardpenalty has it right.  No multiple values, all productcode have the exact same RecurringBillingAmount

Comment: FYI, that is not what you would want a product code to be in almost all situations. Your code should be relational or unique and be an actual code or id

Comment: @yardpenalty, yah no idea man.  I didn't write the software or the database, I'm just the end user trying to make a pricing change for our company.

Comment: @BBE ya sorry, just add the AND equals at end of statement

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select *,
case WHEN RecurringBillingAmount = '29.98' 
     THEN '34.98' 
end as new_amount
from dbo.cards WHERE productcode = '2x $19.99 SUBSCRIPTI'
```

This will add one column into your output.

Since you want to use the new column to replace the old one, please do not include the old one in the select statement.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? Assuming you want to update the table, not just show the change in the query results.

```
UPDATE dbo.cards 
  SET RecurringBillingAmount = '34.98'
WHERE 
  productcode = '2x $19.99 SUBSCRIPTI'
  AND
  RecurringBillingAmount = '29.98';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN RecurringBillingAmount = '29.98' THEN '34.98' 
    ELSE RecurringBillingAmount
END  RecurringBillingAmount
FROM dbo.cards 
WHERE productcode = '2x $19.99 SUBSCRIPTI'
```